# how can i access cloud sql from google kubernetes engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

At first i have delployed cloud sql with postgresql. and then i deployed gke with documents: https://cloud.google.com/support-hub#section-2
i used gcloud tool. and i made gke cluster using auto pilot mode. and made deployment with autoscaler.
and i registered my docker image. and then i expose it with loadbalancer.
Once i build my docker image. and then i excute it in local. it is running well.
but it is not running well in gke server. and suddendly can not connect cloud sql.
so i registered gke external ip in cloud sql connection ips. but it doesn't work...
i want to connect cloud sql from google kubernetes engine.
please help me...

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how do you connect your database for now? If it's work and then goes down? What's your container/pod definition?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere 
connect the database with typeorm in express server. it works well in local backend server. but it doesn't work in google kubernetes engine. my database server construct with cloud sql which is one of gcp service. i don't know exactly when goes down... b.b. how can i know container/pod definition? thank you for your help

Comment: Firstly, what is your connection string to connect Cloud SQL? do you use IP? Cloud SQL proxy? If so in Unix socket or TCP mode? Then, how do you deploy your container (or pod) on kubernetes? Can you detail the command/action that you do for this task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For accessing the Cloud SQL instance from an application running in Google Kubernetes Engine, you can use either the Cloud SQL Auth proxy (with public or private IP), or connect directly using a private IP address. The Cloud SQL Auth proxy is the recommended way to connect to Cloud SQL, even when using private IP.

Referral link :

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine                          [2]https://medium.com/google-cloud/connecting-cloud-sql-kubernetes-sidecar-46e016e07bb4
[3]https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/018_tip_kubernetes_and_google_cloud_sql.html

Answer (score 2):

I recommend following the [Connecting from Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine) page in the documentation.